# How to handle Schedules when moving Jobs to another server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, migration

We are migrating our SQL Server 2008 R2 to another physical server. For this, I will script out all jobs and run it on the target server. My question is about handling the schedules:
When a job is scripted out, there is a parameter called `@schedule_uid` of type uniqueidentifier for the step `sp_add_jobschedule`. Should I include or remove this parameter from the script? Is this value specific to the original server and therefore should not be included? If so, how can I create the matching one on the target server?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience scripting out jobs and running on another servers works fine - including schedulers. 
You might want to check job owner login to appear on destination server.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will change the job owners to 'sa' anyways on the source server. I don't want to sound pedantic but I want to make sure importing schedules along with the jobs won't break something. I tested it on a test server and it looks like imported just fine but don't know how it will work on prod.

Comment: There is nothing pedantic regarding prod servers ;-)